# My "umask" output is "022"- why can't I execute a file I just created without "chmod"?

Tags: permissions, umask

I have a brand-new file called `./foo`, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Hello world'
```

The output of the `umask` command looks like so:

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx

$ umask
022
```

Yet, when I try to execute the brand-new file (no `chmod` yet), I get the following:

```
$ ./foo

zsh: permission denied: ./foo
```

For what it's worth, I get the same thing when I open a `bash` shell:

```
$ bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

bash-3.2$ ./foo

bash: ./foo: Permission denied
```

And when I inspect the file's permissions with `ls -l`, it also appears to not be executable:

```
$ ls -l foo

-rw-r--r--  1 richiethomas  staff  40 Mar  3 10:11 foo
```

When I `chmod` the file, however, it works as expected:

```
$ chmod +x foo

$ ./foo
Hello world

$ ls -l foo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 richiethomas  staff  40 Mar  3 10:11 foo
```

Using [this document](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ecs252/Book/umask.html) as a source, I learned that a `umask` value of `022` means "Owner has all permissions. Everyone else can read and execute, but not write."

If `umask` is telling me that a file's creator (i.e. me) should be able to execute the file by default, why am I not in fact able to do so?

Comment: Is this helpful? [what is the difference between umask and chmod](https://superuser.com/questions/1030110/what-is-the-difference-between-umask-and-chmod)

Comment: @MattiaRighetti thanks but that link doesn't appear to address my question, which is about why the permissions returned from `umask` don't appear to reflect my actual permissions, as reflected in my ability to execute a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know to make a file executable immediately on creation without using hidden steps (like in a function or script) is to create it by *copying* another file that is already executable. You could use this to make a base template, then edit the file as needed.

```
$ echo echo hi > a
$ ./a
-bash: ./a: Permission denied
$ chmod +x a
$ ./a
hi
$ cp a b
$ ./b
hi
```

...but in general, the default behaviors are always there for a reason. Please think about those reasons before changing them. I'm not saying you shouldn't customize your environment however is needed, just that you should be aware of the possible consequences in the specific context. This might save you a bit of time and a few spoons on a dev sandbox, but don't let it go to a company prod system without really thinking it through.

Comment: It makes sense to leave the defaults as they are unless we have a good reason not to.  That said, any idea why the default in this case is that a file's creator can't execute their own file, which they just created?  That seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: Because most files are data, and this is *generally* safer in the unknown broader context. The folk designing the system built it to be easy for me to do quick scripting work, especially on a dedicated private machine, but also easy for sysadmins to manage if the machine is a highly networked production system where very few people should be *creating* new scripts. When in doubt, a more conservative decision is safer, and the risk tolerances of end users vary *wildly*.

Comment: It sounds like this default is designed to address the case where, for example, a malicious user gains access to a system they shouldn't have access to, and creates a destructive script.  In this scenario, with the defaults they way they currently are, that malicious user would be unable to actually execute it without first being given that permission by a sysadmin, which (presumably) that sysadmin wouldn't do.  Is that a correct read of the intent here?

Comment: It's one possible example. What I don't understand is why it's so important that you be able to create an executable in one action. If it's just the time invested, make a function or script, as mentioned above, that automates the steps into a single command. Let the machine to the tediuos bits.

Comment: There's nothing specific I'm trying to accomplish; it's strictly a learning exercise.  I'm trying to better understand file and directory permissions as part of leveling up my terminal skills.  That includes understanding why the defaults are the way they are.  Until I read the answers on this post, it seemed counter-intuitive to me that UNIX would make a file's author jump through `chmod` hoops before allowing them to execute their own file.  Now it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The umask value that you have does reflect the final permissions of your newly created file.

> I learned that a umask value of 022 means "Owner has all permissions. Everyone else can read and execute, but not write."

This is incorrect, `umask` of `022` tells you that newly created files are readable by everyone, but only writable by the owner.

Indeed, default file permission is `666` upon creation and the `022` will set it to `644` which is what you end up with

```
$ umask
022

$ touch file.txt
$ stat -c "%a" file.txt
644

$ ls -la
.rw-r--r-- someuser file.txt
```

If you want to make a file executable by default by exploiting `umask`, then there is no way to achieve that because the default value upon creation is `666`, and for a file to be executable by owner, you would need at least `766`.

To give it execution rights you have to use `chmod` as you did in your OP

```
$ chmod 744 file.txt
$ ls -la
.rwxr--r-- someuser file.txt
```

There are some good explanations [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work) on how `umask` works if you want to dig deeper into this.

If you want to create a file and make it executable with a single command, you could create a function like this in `~/.utils.sh`

```
function touch_rwx() {
    touch $1
    chmod 744 $1
}
```

You could then `source` the `.sh` file and this is the outcome

```
$ touch_rwx file.txt
$ ls -la
.rwxr--r-- file.txt
```

If you use this frequently, I would suggest to add `.utils.sh` in your `PATH` so that you can use it whenever you want in all your newly created shell sessions.

Comment: So, I don't necessarily care about exploiting `umask` to make a file executable.  My main goal is to create a file that is executable as soon as it's created, without having to run `chmod` on it.  One of my mistakes is that I thought `6--` included `execute` permissions for the creator, but now I see that I would need at least `7--` for that.  So how do I create a file that ships with `7--` permissions by default?

Comment: It's not possible with shell builtins, as far as I know. A possible solution would be to create a bash `function` that is going to create a new file and run `chmod` soon after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently learning Linux as we speak and going over this exact subject! So what I've learned is (and please forgive me for any misinformation) 777 is the default permissions for directories (777 is the octal number for granting all permissions for user, group, and other with directories) & 666 is the the default permissions for files (666 is the octal number for granting read & write permissions for files). HERES THE KICKER, THERES NO EXECUTABLES FOR FILES! (i know this is contrary to changing permissions with chmod but stay with me) Since executables are not the default for files you can only calculate removing the ocatal umask number from 666 never counting the executable octal in the equation. Hope this helps!